# How to add text field in custom post without plugin and without using custom field

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm new to WordPress and doesn't much about it. I am making property listing plugin for WordPress I want to add Price field/(numeric type)
.I don't want to use plugin and custom fields. I want the field as shown
[image: As shown]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a metabox to add a new box to the Admin Frontend. If its done, you need a filter to handle the inputs value for the backend. For more detailed helped, you need to provide more informations about your plugin.

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/